# Guardar mejor puntuación en un juego

Tags: c

Lo que quiero hacer es guardar la mejor puntuación obtenida por un usuario en un determinado juego, pero no encuentro la manera de hacerlo, ya que cada vez que abro el juego la variable `mayorpuntuacion` se vuelve a inicializar a 0. Aquí el código(bastante simplificado ya que solo incluyo las partes que tengan que ver con obtener la mayor puntuación para una rápida comprensión):

```
int puntos=0;
int mayorpuntuacion=0;
if (colision(tux,ubuntu))
        {
            puntos=puntos+1;
if(vida==0)
        {
            if (puntos>mayorpuntuacion)
            {
                mayorpuntuacion=puntos;
            }
```

Comment: Si deseas mantener el valor, deberías manejar un histórico utilizando un repositorio de datos dependiendo de tu sistema (archivos planos, bases de datos, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una solucion bastante directa seria usar un archivo para almacenarla, supongamos que se llama "MayorPuntuacion".
Deberas utilizar las funciones para manejo de archivo:

 - `fopen` que abre un archivo, en "r"(read) para lectura y "w"(write) para escritura.

 - `fread` para leer los datos.

 - `fwrite` para escribir datos.

 - `fclose` para cerrar el archivo, es muy importante porque es cuando se escribe el archivo en el disco rigido.
Puedes obtener mas informacion sobre las funciones y todas sus capacidades consultando el comando `man` en unix (o bien en la [pagina web](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) del mismo).

 Entonces al inicializar tu programa debes inicializar la variable leyendo del archivo asi:

```
FILE * f_mayor_puntuacion = fopen("MayorPuntuacion","r");
if(f_mayor_puntuacion){
    fread(&mayorpuntuacion,sizeof(mayorpuntuacion),1,f_mayor_puntuacion);
}
fclose(f_mayor_puntuacion);
```

Y al terminar la ejecucion guardar el archivo para poder recuperar el valor, de la siguiente manera:

```
FILE * f_mayor_puntuacion = fopen("MayorPuntuacion","w");
fwrite(&mayorpuntuacion,sizeof(mayorpuntuacion),1,f_mayor_puntuacion);
fclose(f_mayor_puntuacion);
```

Comment: Una consulta, qué es el `man`? no había leído ese término hasta ahora.

Comment: [`man`](https://linux.die.net/man/) es el comando para _ejecutar_ o _abrir_ el manual de documentación en Linux _(Y quizá en otros sistemas operativos)_.

Comment: Disculpa, asumi que era algo de conocimiento comun, ahora edito mi respuesta para evitar confusiones.